# Is Azure Key Vault appropriate to store encryption keys generated on client applications?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

I have client applications that generate data that is encrypted on the device. The encryption keys are sent over HTTPS to an Azure Function that uses the Azure Key Vault to store the encryption keys so that other authorized clients can get them and decrypt the data.

Here is the piece of code in my Azure Function to perform the job of saving the encryption keys (the secret) in the key vault:

```
    public async Task InsertEncryptionKeyAsync(EncryptionKeyContract encryptionKey)
    {
        Guard.CheckForNull(encryptionKey, nameof(encryptionKey));

        //  Serializes the encryption key information.
        string serializedEncryptionKey = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(encryptionKey);

        //  Pushes the encryption to the Key-Vault.
        var client = new KeyVaultClient(/* Key-vault- access otken*/, new HttpClient());

        await client.SetSecretAsync(Constants.Vault.Url, encryptionKey.FileId.ToKey(), serializedEncryptionKey);
    }
```

**Question**

Is this design an appropriate use of the Azure Key Vault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Azure Key Vault is ment to store keys / secrets so this is a perfect **valid use case**. Depending on who are your clients and what permission they have, you could get rid of the middleware and let the client add the encryption key to the vault. But usually you don't want to grant clients permission to the vault so doing that using a Azure Function looks also fine.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Martin, this is a great use case for KeyVault.

You may wish to lean further on keyvault for it's abilities.

Assuming you are using symmetric encryption on the client, keyvault has wrapKey which is made for storing keys.

Using wrapKey / unwrapKey mean your clients can be granted specific permissions using access policies on what they can do with the keys.

You may also wish to sign and verify the encrypted content to ensure it has not been manipulated on transit.

If you haven't already gone down this route you may wish to investigate Native App AD authentication https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-application-objects which can work on behalf of a user or service principal and thus provide a nice storey for how keyvault access control might work.... but I won't go into detail, as I'm going of track the original question. Notably key vault has a limit of 16 access policies so it's more for an application group not for individual installs or users.

Answer (score 0):

I save all my user's encryption keys in Azure Key vaults allowing access only to web appis as managed entities.

It is a pain to run from localhost but is the most secure way.